# WPF TemplatedBinding of Image by DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have derived the textbox class. In custom textbox class i have defined dependency property by the name of ImageSrc. Here is the code for customcontrol.

**CustomControl.cs**

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static string GetImageSrc(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ImageSrcProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageSrc(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageSrcProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSrcProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageSrc", typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBox ), new PropertyMetadata(""));

}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
<DrawingImage x:Key="ByParticipantSource">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="White"
                             Geometry="M12.555,10.734h-0.91c-1.007,0-1.822-0.815-1.822-1.824V8.325
        c0.402-0.478,0.691-1.046,0.871-1.644c0.019-0.101,0.117-0.151,0.182-0.221c0.349-0.349,0.417-0.938,0.156-1.356
        c-0.037-0.064-0.101-0.119-0.097-0.198c0-0.534,0.002-1.07-0.002-1.604c-0.013-0.645-0.198-1.315-0.65-1.792
        C9.919,1.125,9.416,0.895,8.901,0.797C8.247,0.672,7.564,0.679,6.917,0.844C6.355,0.984,5.829,1.313,5.503,1.8
        C5.216,2.223,5.089,2.737,5.067,3.243C5.06,3.787,5.065,4.332,5.063,4.876c0.013,0.109-0.08,0.183-0.122,0.273
        C4.697,5.597,4.804,6.207,5.201,6.532c0.1,0.07,0.119,0.196,0.156,0.304c0.172,0.539,0.458,1.036,0.821,1.47V8.91
        c0,1.009-0.815,1.824-1.822,1.824H3.443c0,0-1.652,0.456-2.732,2.732v0.912c0,0.504,0.406,0.91,0.91,0.91h12.756
        c0.504,0,0.912-0.406,0.912-0.91v-0.912C14.206,11.19,12.555,10.734,12.555,10.734z"  />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is the Style for the textbox which have to show the image.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl:CustomTextBox}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl:CustomTextBox}">
            <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" >
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSrc}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Grid.Column="1" Template="{DynamicResource HDADMTBScrollViewerControlTemplate}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the tag that i have used where i want to specify the image.

```
<CustomControls:CustomTextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}" Text="Test" WaterMark="By Participant" Margin="0,0,2,5" ImageSrc="ByParticipantSource" />
```

There is some issue in binding which i am unable to understand. Your help will be really appreciated.

**PS**: ImageSrc is actully a string value which contains the key of image.

Comment: You have declared an attched property instead of a regular dependency property. Besides that you can't set the Source property of an Image control to a resource key.

Comment: @Clemens so is there any other way i could pass the resource key of image to style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a regular dependency property instead of an attached property, and change its type to ImageSource:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSrcProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           "ImageSrc", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomTextBox));

    public ImageSource ImageSrc
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSrcProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSrcProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then assign the resource like this:

```
<CustomControls:CustomTextBox ... ImageSrc="{StaticResource ByParticipantSource}" />
```